# RadioButton Spacing Issue with ScrollView

Tags: android, xml, android-scrollview, radio-group, android-radiogroup

I am having a bit of an issue with the spacing of my RadioButtons in my RadioGroup. According to the preview it should look like this:

[image]

But on my phone running KitKat it looks like this:

[image]

This is perplexing because on a phone running Lollipop, it looks prfectly fine with the exact same code:

[image]

For some reason on earlier versions the RadioGroup seems to exceed the parent layout for no apparent reason. I have been stuck on this for hours and have tried every combination of layout_height, gravity, layout_gravity, and weight that there possibly is. From what I gather, it seems to almost be ignoring the layout_below attribute. BUT WHY! Thanks in advance, XML code is below

```
 <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/genderLayout"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/genderText"
                    style="@style/EditProfBoxStyle">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/maleText"
                        android:text="@string/choice_male"
                        style="@style/Text.Medium.EditProfile"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/femaleText"
                        android:text="@string/choice_female"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/maleText"
                        style="@style/Text.Medium.EditProfile" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/bothText"
                        android:text="@string/choice_both"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/femaleText"
                        style="@style/Text.Medium.EditProfile"/>

                    <RadioGroup
                        android:id="@+id/genderGroup"
                        style="@style/RadioGroupStyle"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/bothText"
                        android:layout_alignTop="@id/maleText">

                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/maleCheckBox"
                            style="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="0dp"/>

                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/femaleCheckBox"
                            style="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="0dp"/>

                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/bothCheckBox"
                            style="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="0dp"/>
                    </RadioGroup>
                </RelativeLayout>
```

RadioGroup Style:

```
<style name="RadioGroupStyle">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_alignParentRight">true</item>
        <item name="android:layout_alignParentEnd">true</item>
    </style>
```

**Edit: The issues is definitely with the scrollview I am using as a parent.**
If I remove the scrollview everything goes back to normal. And I have included `fillviewport=true` so I have no idea what the problem is

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.richluick.android.roomie.ui.activities.EditProfileActivity">

        <!--Relative layout with RadioButtons from above goes here-->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of structuring all of the text views and radio buttons together in one shot, it might make more sense to structure them as rows, and then within the rows position the checkboxes with the same layout parameters.

I've heard more than a few times that using too many views is taboo. That was the case in Android <1.5, and you still want to be weary of using too many views in a layout, but sometimes even adding just one extra layer of view depth can make all the difference.  Adding an extra view does cause one extra object in the object tree, but it also makes the layout process more precise and easier so it's a trade-off.

Try something like this (note: it's untested - just giving you a general sense)

```
 <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/genderLayout"
                android:layout_below="@+id/genderText"
                style="@style/EditProfBoxStyle">
      <LinearLayout
           android:id="@+id/male"
           android:orientation="horizontal"
      >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/maleText"
                    android:text="@string/choice_male"
                    style="@style/Text.Medium.EditProfile"/>

                <RadioGroup
                    android:id="@+id/genderGroup"
                    style="@style/RadioGroupStyle"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/bothText"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@id/maleText">
      </LinearLayout>
      <LinearLayout.... (etc etc)
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I had thought about doing something like this. This would just make it more difficult to setup the radiogroups as id have to make my own with check boxes. I actually have determined that the issue is definitely with the scrollview parent layout. If I remove that everything goes back to normal

Comment: Huh - very interesting.  I'd be curious to see your solution when you figure it out bud.